# Zend Framework 2: Creating forms from configuration - how to fix ServiceNotCreatedException

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I want to create a form in Zend Framework 2 from configuration, similar as described in the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#creation-via-factory). So instead of doing this in the form class for every element:

```
// [...]

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'fname',
    'type' => 'text',     
));

// [...]v
```

I want to do it like this:

```
// [...]

$form = $factory->createForm(array(
    'elements' => array(
        array(
            'spec' => array(
                'name' => 'fname',
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        ),
    ),
));

// [...]
```

Since I am new to the framework, I am still a bit unsure as where things go & what is the correct way to do things, but I think I am on a good track – I just need to get things working to understand them more.

Currently my code results in an exception which leaves me a bit puzzled, although I understand it somehow:

```
An exception was raised while creating "MyForm"; no instance returned
```

Besides my confusion, I already have an idea where my code might go wrong.

The form class looks pretty simple because the actual elements won't be injected here:

```
namespace My\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setAttribute('action', '/some-action');
    }
}
```

The configuration for the form elements looks like this:

```
namespace My\Form;

use Zend\Form\Factory;

class MyFormFactory extends Factory
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $factory = new Factory();

        $form = $factory->createForm(array(
            'elements' => array(
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'name' => 'fname',
                        'type' => 'text',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));

        return $form;
    }
}
```

To wire the two together, I have this service manager configuration in the module's `module.config.php`:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'MyForm' => function ($servicemanager) {
            $form = new \My\Form\MyForm();
            $factory = $servicemanager->get('MyFormFactory');
            $form->add($factory);
            return $form;
        },
        'MyFormFactory' => function ($servicemanager) {
            $factory = new \My\Form\MyFormFactory();
            return $factory;
        },
    ),
),
```

And last but not least, the controller:

```
 namespace My\Controller;


use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MyForm');

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $form,
        ));
    }
}
```

As already said, the only thing that happens is the exception which is actually pretty clear: The MyForm class does not return an instance. To fix this, I already tried to return something, but that did not do anything.

What needs to be changed to get the form created? Is my approach any good or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Try to change this `$factory = $servicemanager->get('MyFormFactory');` to `$factory = $servicemanager->getServiceLocator()->get('MyFormFactory');`

Comment: @blackbishop This results in a `Fatal Error: Call to undefined method Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::getServiceLocator()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a form via config, you will need to *use* the `Zend\Form\Factory` which will return the form element based on the configuration you provide it. Lets call this the "FormFactory".

However to register this form with the `FormElementManager` as a service called 'MyForm' you will need to *also* create a service manager factory. This "factory" is a class implementing `Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface`. Lets call this the "ServiceFactory".

If I were to correct your code, I would do so in the following way.

- Delete the class `MyForm`. There is no real need to actually extend the base form `Zend\Form\Form`; this is because you are only setting the form's attributes which can be done so via the `FormFactory` (you give it the config of these attributes and it will return a new form with them already set).
- Delete `MyFormFactory`. In order to create our new form we do NOT need to extend the form factory or create a new instance of it, instead we *use* it's API in client code.
- Remove the config under `service_manager`. We should register our forms with the 'FormElementManager' (using the `form_elements' config key). A 'plugin manager' configured to return form elements.

With these changes, you are then able to create your form with just one "ServiceFactory". For example.

```
namespace My\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class MyFormFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $formElementManager)
    {
        // Get the config of the new form
        $config = $this->getElementConfig($formElementManager);

        // Get the service manager
        $serviceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();

        // Get the form factory (service that creates the form)
        // from the service manager, FormFactory is the default
        $formFactory = new \Zend\Form\Factory($formElementManager); 

        // Create the form using the factory and config and then return it
        return $formFactory->create($config);
    }

    /** Return the config for the factory **/
    protected function getElementConfig(ServiceLocatorInterface $formElementManager)
    {
        // you could use the form element manager / service manager
        // here to load the config from elsewhere...
        return [
            'name' => 'myform',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Form',
            'attributes' => [
                'method' => 'post',
                'action' => '/foo/bar',
            ],
            'fieldsets' => [
                /....
            ],
            'elements' => [
               //...
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

Then in your module.config.php you can register the factory as the new service

```
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        'MyForm' => 'My\Factory\MyFormFactory',
    ],
],
```

Notice above the config is under the 'form_elements' key. As we are registering the service with the form element manager, your controller code should also be updated.

```
$serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form = $serviceManager->get('FormElementManager')->get('MyForm');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer – looks really good to me, but could you please elaborate where `'FormFactory'` comes from in `$formFactory = $serviceManager->get('FormFactory'); `? Currently, I created a 'loop' – the `MyFormFactory` tries to get itself via the service manager, which is wrong of course.

Comment: @Sven Sorry, I never tested the code. I've updated, `$formFactory` should be an instance of `Zend\Form\Factory`.

Comment: Amazing, thank you, got it to work exactly as you said!

Comment: And, with ZF3, instead of the controller asking the ServiceManager for MyForm, you'd have a controller factory that did that...

Comment: @AlexP, using the Form Element Manager, and other managers, is obviously the right way for all of a form's dependencies, but where did you learn to do this?  None of the books or tutorials I've seen do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

A handful of things here that might make your life easier in the future.

1. ZF2 ships with a `AbstractPluginManager` specifically for Forms and Form Elements called the `FormElementManager`. Forms can be configured from this manager using the `form_elements` config key.

   Documentation on this found here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html

   Use this instead of the general `ServiceManager`.
2. In your `MyForm` factory callback, `$form->add()` is expecting an instance of `ElementInterface` or a `Traversable`, you're passing it a factory. I assume this is throwing an `InvalidArgumentException`. Check your logs for this. I assume this is the source of your problem.

   Additionally, in your `MyFormFactory` where you're attempting to return a form from the factory constructor. That's going to produce some interesting results (plus breaks SRP), I'd rethink that class entirely.
3. For best practice, avoid the use of the `ServiceManager` within a controller if you can. I know it's in there, and I know it's an easy thing to just grab should you need a service, but that form should really be injected into your controller in the controller's own factory (under the `controllers` -> `factories` config key)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I didn't accept it (I think it was not specific enough for my skill level) I learned a lot while trying to follow your advice, for example constructor injection.